# Starting parsnips in cells

Tags: seedlings

Everything I have read online has told me that parsnips need to be seeded directly as they don’t like being transplanted from pot to ground.

However our allotment plot is renown for the mice getting to even the smallest seeds of planted directly into the ground.

Is it possible to start Parsnips off in cells or pots I was considering growing them in the cardboard ones that allow roots to grow through and can just be planted out as soon as the seedling shows as this should allow the parsnip to break up the cardboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a source](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/vegetables/parsnips/container-grown-parsnips.htmwhow.com/edible/vegetables/parsnips/container-grown-parsnips.htm) that says you can successfully start parsnips in containers and transplant them. [Here's another source](https://harvesttotable.com/parsnips-seed-starting-tips/) that says they can be transplanted, but that it's difficult to do successfully. Note that it says difficult, not impossible.

Many plants that people recommend against transplanting, actually can be started in cells and transplanted if you're careful. I have started corn (maize) in cells and transplanted it, even though basically no one does that, and I found references saying that they wouldn't transplant well. I had an excellent corn crop that year.

Since you know that sowing turnips directly into the ground won't work in your plot, it makes sense to try starting them in containers. When you transplant them, be particularly gentle with the roots. (It is a root crop after all, so you don't want to damage the tap root.) The decomposable cardboard pots sounds like a good idea, since you won't be disturbing the roots when you transplant.

It occurs to me that mice sometimes like to chew up cardboard to make their nests out of, so there's a risk that they chew on the cardboard pots and disturb the plants. If there's any extra cardboard sticking up above ground level when you transplant plant them, it might be a good idea to trim that off.